# How can i get the whole error stack when any error come in vue.js application?

Tags: vuejs2

I when to log the error coming in vue.js application . How can i get whole error stack for the error.

filename , In which line and row of file .
The error description
and whole error detail

I am trying the `window.onerror`  but it is not giving file name of the of error log .

Any idea ?

Comment: Look in the terminal?

Comment: I want to log this error. How to get this in variable . How to get the file name in which error is occur ?